# How to implement Poseidon hash function into a smart contract

Tags: solidity, hash-algorithm, zero-knowledge, merkleization, circom

I am building a Merkle tree inside a smart contract, and I want to use the Poseidon hash function to later prove that an element belongs to the tree through a ZK proof. The problem is that I cannot find a library where this hash function is implemented, can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using circom for writing your ZKP circuits, you can generate the contract using this script from circomlibjs: https://github.com/iden3/circomlibjs/blob/main/src/poseidon_gencontract.js

This test script shows how to generate, deploy & interact with the contract: https://github.com/iden3/circomlibjs/blob/main/test/poseidoncontract.js